# PHP regular expression not working in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this bit of code:

```
import re
word = 'baz'
regexp = re.compile(r'a[s|z|d]')
if regexp.search(word) is not None:
    print 'matched'
else:
    print 'not matched'
```

Which I got from SO. That works and prints `matched`. Now I am trying to get the same thing to work for a different regex which I've got working in PHP.

This `/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$` regex works to filter out these results

```
mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080 # correctly matches
word_with_characters_I_dont_want-(1) # correctly does not match
```

I want to change the above python code to do the same but I'm not familiar with python and I'm struggling. I've so far got:

```
import re
word = 'mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080'
regexp = re.compile(r'/[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$')
if regexp.search(word) is not None:
    print 'matched'
else:
    print 'not matched'
```

But this gives me the following result:

```
mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080 # not matched
word_with_characters_I_dont_want-(1) # not matched
```

And I want the code to produce this result

```
mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080 // matched
word_with_characters_I_dont_want-(1) // not matched
```

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: You already have 2 answers, but anyways, this is the tool I always use to check my regex: http://regex101.com (they should actually call it regex911, because by the time I use it I'm already freaking out, lol)

Comment: `a[s|z|d]` matches `a|` also.

Comment: change the above to `a[szd]` if you actually mean `as` or `az` or `ad`

Comment: Thanks guys. Most helpful and I will checkout regex101.com too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you wrongly mean  `/` as line start. Replace `/` with `^` (*start of the line anchor*).

```
regexp = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$')
```

And note that `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` would be written as `\w`. So you could reduce the above regex to `r'^[\w.-]+$'`.

Comment: This worked! You sir are a genius. I will accept as soon as I can :)

Answer (score 3):

Python regular expressions do not start with `/` like in some other languages.  So, Python is trying to match a literal `/` character.  You need to remove this:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$')
```

Demo:

```
>>> import re
>>> word = 'mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080'
>>> regexp = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+$')
>>> regexp.search(word)
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 36), match='mixed_CASE_word_00008908908808908080'>
>>>
```